# ASP.net server error in '/' Application Inherits

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I add a webform to my page, I keep getting the error below:
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type '`WebApplication9.WebForm11`'.

If I remove the Inherits portion it will run.  It will also run if I add the inherits portion on one particular reference: `Inherits="WebApplication9.GaugePro"`

But if I do Inherits on anything else it will error out.  Any idea what I did wrong.  This just started happening....

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm11.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication9.WebForm11" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try changing the **CodeBehind** to **CodeFile** as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebForm11.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication9.WebForm11" %>
```

It may occurs in another case also, when you create web application project, then the directive should be:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm11.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication9.WebForm11" %>
```

For the website project, the first one should work fine.